# Does Android cache app array resources?

Tags: android, resources

Does Android cache the result of `Resource#getIntArray(int)`? I've poked around in the source code but got lost when it came to the native code.

I've followed the trail from `getIntArray(int)`, which calls into the native method `AssetManager#getArrayIntResource(int)`.

I guess I'm also asking how expensive is calling `Resources#getIntArray(int)`, as it's a method I use frequently? Should I implement my own caching?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by some kind folks on Freenode, no, Android doesn't appear to cache the result.